# Finding a plane which contains a certain line and is perpendicular to another

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a question on my worksheet which reads the following:
$2$ lines are given. $g_1: x= (3,1,3) + t(1,2,-2)$ and $g_2: x=(-2,1,-1) + s(0,1,1)$

the first part is asking if the $2$ lines intersect and if they don't I should calculate the distance between them. I did this, it was easy.

the second part is asking me to find the plane $E_1$ which includes the line $g_1$ and is perpendicular to $g_2$. How do I do that? I thought of the equation of the described plane. As it should include the like $g_1$ then the first part should be: $(3,1,3) + t(1,2,-2)$ but how to I find the second part?

Comment: A plan containing a given line, for example containing the axe of Y can not be perpendicular to any arbitrary line, for example the line y=x and z=0. is it  possible in the case of your problem? Maybe yes maybe not. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I would say:

Find the equation of the plane E1 in the form:  $a\,x_1+b\,x_2+c\,x_3+d=0 $

- the directional vector of the line   $g_2$ is a orthogonal vector 'n' of plane $E_2\Rightarrow \vec{n}=\vec{n}(0,1,1)$

$\Rightarrow a\,x_1+b\,x_2+c\,x_3+d = 0\cdot x_1+1\cdot x_2+1\cdot x_3+d = 0$

- E1 includes the line g1

$\Rightarrow x_2+x_3 + d = 1+2t+3-2t + d = 4+d=0 \Rightarrow d = -4$

So the search equation  $ E_2:\quad x_2+x_3 - 4 = 0 $